# How shells handle redirection

Tags: c, shell

I have to code my own shell in C, and I'm currently dealing with the `> < >> <<` operators. I handle the `|` (pipe) but i can't understand all the priority for splitting my line.

For something like `ls -la | cat -e ; ps` i'll do the `ls -la | cat -e` and then the `ps`, nothing difficult.

With the redirection `< > << >>` operators what is the order of precedence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell handle the redirection operators in order of their appearance (or from beginning to the end of command, of from left to right).

This behavior was [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07):

> If more than one redirection operator is specified with a command, the
>   order of evaluation is from beginning to end.

Answer (score 2):

Scan left to right, stop and execute what you've got if you see `;`.  `<<` can be a bit tricky because you have to remember *terminator* and the remainder after the `;` and go back to the remainder after you've read the "inline" data

Consider:

```
cat << EOF | cat | cat | cat | cat ; echo hello
abc
EOF
echo world
```

The output:

```
abc
hello
world
```

Here's a slightly more complex version:

```
cat << EOF | cat | cat | cat | cat ; echo hello ; cat << EOF ; echo day
abc
EOF
turkey
EOF
echo world
```

And the output:

```
abc
hello
turkey
day
world
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest answer to this question `dup` and `dup2` system calls.

For more insight, follow the code below

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define READ_END 0
#define WRITE_END 1

int 
main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
  pid_t pid;
  int fd[2];

  pipe(fd);
  pid = fork();

  if(pid==0)
   {
     printf("i'm the child used for ls \n");
     dup2(fd[WRITE_END], STDOUT_FILENO);
     close(fd[WRITE_END]);
     execlp("ls", "ls", "-al", NULL);
   }
  else
   { 
     pid=fork();

     if(pid==0)
      {
        printf("i'm in the second child, which will be used to run grep\n");
        dup2(fd[READ_END], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd[READ_END]);
        execlp("grep", "grep", "alpha",NULL);
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

In short what `dup` and `dup2` does is they close you default `stdout` when a command is run and map it to any `IPC` mechanisms, here `pipe`. So when the command is run, they don't spit their output on screen. Rather they throw it on that `IPC` now another child process created by `fork` system call which was monitoring the `IPC` for any inputs now gets activated and it takes the input from the previous command's output and run another command on it and then finally throw the output on the screen.

Now as far as the order goes, the command which has the least/no dependency on any other command is run first and then other commands. Sometimes it depends on how you have written the commands. For more info on preference, follow posix guides